# the sharigan question about the fading sharingans and the ones that remain

Tags: naruto

I am still puzzled guys how come itachi died but sasuke still has his eyes but when obito died kakashi lost his sharingan eyes and all the skills it came with.is there something im missing or its something the writers just came up with on the spot